# Android: Need to apply linear time interpolation on accelerometer data

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, linear-interpolation

The raw data retrieved from the Accelerometer sensor (samsung galaxy S) needs to be processed in order to create robust templates for each subject so i need to apply linear time interpolation because Due to the android SDK, the phone only outputs data values whenever there is a change in the sensor. Therefore, the time intervals between two sample points (acceleration values) are not always equal, which requires time interpolation. This ensures that the time-interval between two sample-points will be fixed.

So please help me how can i apply interpolation method on this data as the data will be containing X, Y, Z values. (any link for interpolation method will be most welcomed)

Update: These accelerometer data is generating from a persons walk while phone is in his waist pocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that interpolation will meet your requirements?

To interpolate a value you need to know where previous and next points are, and if you are doing a real time analysis you only know where are the previous points.

I suggest you to have a look to this project: [pedometer](http://code.google.com/p/pedometer/)

It's using accelerometer for the same objective as you and the code is available.

Regards.

Comment: you might be right what concerns his question, but could you still answer it for the general case? Because I definitely need interpolation. I am using the data for machine learning algorithms and I have the previous and upcoming points

Answer (score 1):

Android sensor give output at constant at rate specified while registering. No need of interpolation